# What is the big-O of this for loop...?

Tags: c++, big-o

The first loop runs O(log n) time but the second loop's runtime depends on the counter of the first loop, If we examine it more it should run like (1+2+4+8+16....+N) I just couldn't find a reasonable answer to this series...

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i = i * 2)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < i; j++)
    {
        //const time
    }
}
```

Comment: A key term that you might find helpful is "[geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is like :

1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ....+ N

= 2 ^ [O(log(N) + 1] - 1

= O(N)

Comment: this helped me a lot thanks.
bcz 1+2+4+8...+N == log(N) we can replace the N in the sum formula with a log(N) and since 2^log(N) == N we get O(N)

Answer (score 4):

Just like you said. If N is power of two, then 1+2+4+8+16....+N is exactly 2*N-1 (sum of geometric series) . This is same as O(N) that can be simplified to N.

Comment: don't you mean ((2^n) -1) I am just confused bcz this yields a very big number and when I run the code for test (n=100) the total number of loops run is 127 whereas if I use this formula it should be 1.2676506e+30 which is a crazy big number

Comment: @ammaralbakri The formula `2^(n+1) - 1` is for the series `1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^n`. However, you have a different `n` in your question. The sum does not go to `2^n`, but to `N`. So replace `2^n` with `N` in the formula -- the sum is `2^(n+1) - 1` == `2*2^(n) - 1` == `2*N - 1`.